# Why is the force along $x$ direction not $0$ on bumpy surface?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

Near earth the gravitational force is $F=-mg\hat{y}$ and the potential energy is given by $U=mgy$. The force points straight down with no horizontal $x$ component.

In [this](https://youtu.be/9ta5ul9x6WE?list=PLyQSN7X0ro203puVhQsmCj9qhlFQ-As8e&t=907)(don't have to click) video the professor shows a curve and clearly the potential energy varies with $x$ because the height varies with $x$:
[image]

$$U=mgy = mgf(x)$$
Good so far. But $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x} = -F_x = mgf'(x)$. Suddenly the $x$ component of the force is non zero.  Since gravity is acting straight down, I'm not able to make sense how this vertical force can produce a horizontal component. Any help?

Comment: The gravity force is still towards $ \hat y$ but the magnitude of the force is a function of x

Comment: @Eli I don't understand how your comment resolves the problem. At all the locations where $f'(x)=0$, we have $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}=mgf'(x)=0$. But, the gravitational force acting on the object is $-mg$ everywhere. I have no clue what the professor was trying to explain in that segment.

Comment: Please don't post videos. Summarize what you're asking in written form, so people don't have to watch a video to understand the question.

Comment: @BenCrowell I had already done that and clearly mentioned that clicking the video is not necessary. Video link is provided to avoid dealing with questions about context. Is there a policy in SE against linking the source that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're missing is that **the force of gravity isn't the only force involved**.

The potential $U(y)=mgy$ is a function of $y$, **not** directly a function of $x$. In order to get a potential as a function of $x$, we need a function that gives us $y$ as a function of $x$, so we can plug in this function and define $U(x)$ as being equal to $U(y(x))=mgy(x)$.

This function $y(x)$ is decided by the shape of the ground. The ground is only important because it *keeps things from falling further*, which means it must *exert a force that counters gravity*, namely, the normal force. The function $y(x)$ is, indirectly, a description of the normal force, which means that the potential $U(x)$ incorporates **both** gravity **and** the normal force.

When you're at a point where $dU/dx\neq 0$, you can see based on the equations that $dy/dx\neq0$. Since the normal force is always perpendicular to the surface, $dy/dx\neq 0$ means that the normal force isn't completely vertical - it has a nonzero horizontal component. Therefore, the horizontal force you're asking about is the horizontal component of the normal force.

Comment: Oh I thought normal force cannot contribute to potential energy because it cannot do any work as it is always perpendicular to the motion/surface.  Looks I'm wrong.. so if I understand your response correctly, we can split the normal force into components and the $x$ component of normal force is the $x$ component of resultant force?

Comment: @pooja In this particular case (where all you have is gravity and the normal force, no friction or other forces involved), yes.

Comment: Ok I get this. Thank you so much. You're awesome:) Just trying to prove your point: $$y=\sin x\\ U(x)=mg\sin x \Rightarrow F_x = -mg\cos x$$  
(contd)

Comment: @pooja Indeed. If you were to draw the free-body diagram with gravity and the normal force at any point on that surface (keeping in mind that the inclination angle of the ground at the point $x$ is $\theta=\tan^{-1}(dy/dx)$), you will find the same result.

Comment: @pooja Precisely, though the "velocity vector" you're computing here is more properly called the _tangent vector_ to the curve $(x(t),y(t))$. It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with a physical velocity, after all, but it _does_ represent the vector tangent to the curve, no matter what $t$ means.

Comment: I'll try FBD as you said. Got stuck after parameterizing haha

Comment: Hey could you please see where I'm doing wrong:  $$N = mg\cos\theta\\N_x = -mg\cos\theta\sin\theta = \dfrac{-mg\cos x}{1+\cos^2x}$$

But I should get $-mg\cos x$ right?

Comment: @pooja This should probably be asked as a separate question, because we're nearing the point where we won't be able to use MathJax in the comments (since they'll be automatically be moved to chat where such a thing is impossible).

Comment: Okay I'll post a new questiona nd tag you. Thank you so much:)

Comment: @probably_someone I'm unable to understand your answer. Wouldn't you agree that the normal force acting on the particle depends on the particle's trajectory as a function of time : $\mathbf{r}(t)$? Imagine the surface to be $y=x^2$. If I leave a particle of mass $m$ at $x=0$ at rest, the normal force on the particle is equal to $mg$. However, if I let go of the particle at $x=-1$ and allow it slide down this parabolic path, the normal force acting on the particle when it reaches $x=0$ will be greater than $mg$ since there's normal acceleration involved. (contd.)

Comment: Although I've considered only $x=0$, it applies to all points on the path $y=x^2$. The normal force is fixed by $\mathbf{r}(t)$ and not just by the position $\mathbf{r}$.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example:

[image]

The position vector to the mass is:

$$\vec{R}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} x\\ y \left( x \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

with $y(x)=a(\alpha)\,x$
$$\vec{R}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} x\\ a(\alpha)\,x
\end {array} \right] 
\tag 1$$

To obtain the equation of motion I will use the NEWTON method.

the generalized coordinate is $x$ and the applied force is the gravitation force

$$\vec{F}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 0\\ -mg\end {array}
 \right]
\tag 2$$

EOM's

$$J^T\,M\,J\,\ddot{x}=J^T\,\vec{F}\tag 3$$

where :

$$J=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 1\\ a \left( \alpha
 \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

$$M= \left[ \begin {array}{cc} m&0\\ 0&m\end {array}
 \right] 
$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\ddot{x}={\frac {mga \left( \alpha \right) }{m+ \left( a \left( \alpha
 \right)  \right) ^{2}m}}
$$

so you see the gravitation force $\vec{F}$ equation (2) have always component toward the y direction ($-m\,g$) . the components of the "force" equation (3) $J^T\,\vec{F}$ is a generalized force which depend on your choice  of the 
generalized coordinate.

edit:

$$J^T\,\vec{F}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -mga \left( \alpha \right) \end {array}
 \right]
$$