# Force along $x$ direction on a bumpy surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, potential-energy, vector-fields

Gravitational potential energy near earth is given by$$U(y)=mgy$$

Suppose a bumpy surface is described as $y=\sin(x)$, then $U$ varies with $x$:
$$U(x) = mg\sin x $$
Then the force along $x$ is given by
$$F_x =-\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x}= -mg\cos x$$

Since gravity is vertical, the only other force is normal force. So I think $F_x$ equals the *horizontal component* of the normal force.

[image]

$$N=mg\cos\theta\\ \Rightarrow N_x = -mg\cos\theta\sin\theta = \dfrac{-mg\cos x}{1+\cos^2x}$$
because $\tan \theta = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \cos x$

Why is $F_x\ne N_x$ ? What am I doing wrong?

---

Original question for reference : [Why is the force along $x$ not $0$ on the bumpy surface?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/516557/why-is-the-force-along-x-direction-not-0-on-bumpy-surface)

Comment: @probably_someone

Comment: Isn't that because you took the partial derivative for force only in x direction but the potential function is actually representative of both x and y directions even though you could define it in only x terms.

Comment: Not sure I'm correct but I think the component of force along $y$ is $mg$ and in $x$ direction it is $-mg\cos x$. This $x$ component of force must equal the $x$ component of the normal force. See somwthing wrong?

Comment: Yes of course , the only 'true' force acting is mg in y direction others are only reaction forces , I'll try to post an answer

Comment: Ok.. thanks:) It seems normal force has to provide $x$ component of the force since there are no other forces. Excited to see your answerXD

Comment: @AjayMohan interesting.. I haven't thought about that. Looks replacing the curve with a tangent is messing up somehow hmm..

Comment: @pooja I am trying to understand your y(x) function. It seems like you are describing the bumpy surface as a sine wave. Is it your intention that U(x) will have negative values?

Comment: Ahh just noticed $U(x)$ takes on negative values too. Should have made it $y = 1+\sin x$. But only the difference in potential energy matters... so math wise no issue  right? @BobD

Comment: Yes she's describing the surface as sine wave

Comment: Yeah no issue in maths

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
As you can see from the above example the potential function can be broken into components just like force functions.In the example demonstrated above the actual axis is the diagonal line and the force function has been broken into two components along two axes inclined at $45^°$ to the diagonal axis,consequently the potential function along the diagonal axis also breaks into the two potential functions related to the perpendicular axes.Your question is similar.
The mg force acting along the vertical breaks into force components $mgsin\theta$ along the slope of sine curve surface and a normal component to surface $mgcos\theta$ ,the normal reaction from surface exactly balances this normal component of actual force.Now that they've cancelled off exactly only $mgsin\theta$ is in the picture.This force too breaks into horizontal and vertical components further.The horizontal component is $mgsin\theta cos\theta$ which you've also arrived at.You started off in the wrong direction only when you thought that the potential function being expressed only in terms of x will be responsible for forces only in the x direction.Even though the function is solely dependent in x ,it is the total potential energy.It is here that the vertical component of $mgsin\theta$ comes to the frame.$-mgcosx$ is the net force acting on the body and not the component of $mgsin\theta$ working in only horizontal direction ,you need to consider its vertical component as well.

Comment: Oh  $-mg\cos x$ like the function $ax$ in your graph. And it must be further resolved into $x,y$ components ? Thank you so much! It's getting late here... I'll get back in the morning... have a nice day/night:)